Using is_XXX_v<> in C++14
I'm trying to port a C++17 project to an exotic platform that doesn't have anything newer than C++14. The C++17 project I'm trying to port to C++14 uses a lot of calls to is_XXX_v functions, e.g. is_integral_v, is_floating_point_v and is_same_v, which are unavailable in C++14.
My C++ knowledge is very limited so I'm wondering if it's easily possible to emulate those is_XXX_v calls in C++14 or does that require a major rewrite of the code?

I'm affraid you will have to write them yourself, for instance template<typename T> static constexpr bool is_xxx_v = is_xxx<T>::value. Maybe the preprocessor could help here.

@edrezen IIRC Unless that is done in a cpp file you'll get multiple definition errors.

Searching and reading documentation is an important skill. You should gain this skill ASAP.

Once you understand What is the purpose of _t aliases and _v variable templates for type traits?, you'll automatically understand the solution.

I would also recommend  this post and good c++ book which mention that _v versions are helper templates . In particular the post mentions "is_integral_v is helper template for is_integral<T>::value"

Although if a user will read through the suggested dupes they will understand the issue thoroughly, I believe there is a merit to this post - as a simple and straightforward question about a replacement for the _v variables. Future users might benefit from that. Reopened.

@wohlstad No, you're just reopening the post that you've answered even though dupes exist for it and this also promotes bad questions like this which do not show any research effort. A quick look at the documentation and the dupes will provide the answer.  As long as the user can get the answer from the dupes, it can be closed as a dupe. It is trivial by reading the dupes.

The question is simple and clear. It also might help others with a similar problem, without having to delves into the rather complicated posts in the suggested dupes. Therefore I think it is useful here.

@edrezen I think adding the definitions will not work - see the side note in my answer.

@wohlstad, good point, I missed the point that inline variables are not there in c++14

@edrezen thanks, also assuming the OP is always using the std:: prefix (which is good practice) - it's a problem to add definitions to namespace std.

Chances are good that the code uses other C++17 features that are harder to replace. I would be surprised if the author would impose a C++17 compiler requirement on the user just so that they can use this syntactic sugar to type a few words less.

@user17732522 I'm afraid you're right. After adapting the is_xxx_v references I've now stumbled across the next issue: The code uses tons of compile-time if constexpr statements and AFAICS it would require some major pain to port that code back to something C++14 can understand :/

@Andreas Yes, replacing those requires significant changes to the functions. They need to be replaced with some form of template specialization for the different if constexpr branches. There is no easy way around it. (On the other hand that is why if constexpr is so nice to use: It avoids having to write convoluted template specializations.)

@user17732522 Sounds like a job for AI ;)

The _v variable templates that were added to the traits in C++17 are just syntactic sugar for using their ::value member.
As you can see in the documentation (1,2,3) this is the way the _v variable templates are defined:
template< class T >
inline constexpr bool is_integral_v = is_integral<T>::value;
template< class T >
inline constexpr bool is_floating_point_v = is_floating_point<T>::value;
template< class T, class U >
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;

Therefore you can simply use:
is_integral<T>::value         // for `is_integral_v`
is_floating_point<T>::value   // for `is_floating_point_v`
is_same<T, U>::value          // for `is_same_v`

They are all available since C++11.
A side note:
It would be the simplest if you could add the definitions above (for is_integral_v  etc.) to your code base, but this will not work because:

inline variables are from C++17.
I assume you are using the std:: prefix (as good practice dictates) and you shouldn't add definitions to namespace std (except template specializations) - see here.


So I can replace all references to is_integral_v with is_integral etc. and it won't break the code?

You need to replace it with is_integral<...>::value.

Actually for std::is_xxx, instantiation of the class is enough: std::is_xxx{} followed by an implicit conversion to its value type works, but you can go one step further and force the conversion through a function call: std::is_xxx{}().

@Red.Wave thanks, I was not aware of this option. I see that it works (using MSVC). However I'm not sure I would recommend it, since I believe it's more readable and also common to use the ::value member explicitly.

@wohlstad it's part of std::integral_constant interface. I personally find anything more readable than scope operator(::). I just keep it for definitions and namespaces. That's a matter of preference, but only if you know it exists.

@Red.Wave cheers, it's always nice to learn something new.
